# scipy solve_ivp Error: 'Required step size is less than spacing between numbers'

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, differential-equations

so i'm trying to calculate the time required to reach specific height of rocket. I'm doing this with differential equation of 2nd order, where im taking in account for loss of mass during flight (becouse of fuel burning) and air resistance. But i can't seem to get it to work, i get  'Required step size is less than spacing between numbers' error. I'm using scipy.optimize.solve_ivp. It seems to work if i take out air resistance.

Im coding in python 3 with anaconda distribution

Here's the code:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np

#data
h = 1_000_000 #height of sattelite
n = 100 #number of points
m_rate = 4000 #fuel burn rate
m_satellite = 10_000 #ali ro*V
g_earth = 9.81
F_t = 12_500_000*2 #thrust (F_t = v_e * m_rate)
ro_air = 1.225 #air density
A_rocket = 58 #m^2
C_d = 0.5 #drag coefficient
m_start = 1_350_000 + 150_000 + m_satellite #starting weight of rocket

t = np.linspace(0, 500, n)

def m(t, m_rate=m_rate, m_start=m_start):
    return m_start - m_rate*t

#without air resistance
#def a_rocket(t, y, g_earth=g_earth, F_t=F_t, h=h):
#    h, v = y
#    return np.array([v, ((F_t/m(t)) - g_earth)])

#with air resistance
def a_rocket(t, y, g_earth=g_earth, F_t=F_t, h=h):
    h, v = y
    return np.array([v, ((F_t/m(t)) - (g_earth) - ((ro_air*0.5*A_rocket*v**2*C_d)/m(t)))])

h_rocket = solve_ivp(a_rocket, t_span=[t[0], t[-1]], y0=[0, 0], t_eval=t) #differential equation 2. order
print(h_rocket)
```

And here's the error that scipy gives me:

```
- message: 'Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.'
- nfev: 1070
- njev: 0
- nlu: 0
- sol: None
- status: -1
- success: False
- t: array([,...
- t_events: None
- y: array([[,...
- y_events: None
```

Comment: Your rocket equation is wrong (but that is probably not the error). Force is the change in impulse, so you have `F=(m(t)*v(t))'`. To avoid additional derivatives, make the impulse the second variable, then `p'(t)=F(t,...), x'(t)=v(t)=p(t)/m(t)`. Also, the air density changes with height, this makes a difference in this situation.

Comment: Your mass goes negative, as `4_000 * 500 = 2_000_000`, which is larger than `m_start`.